# Using LINQ to see if a nested property appears in an array of ints

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a class called Business, a class called Tag and a class called BusinessTagLink.

Both Business and Tag have the following property:

`public virtual IList<BusinessTagLink>? BusinessTagLinks { get; set; }`

and every business is linked to one or more tags via the BusinessTagLink table.

My BusinessTagLink class looks like this:

```
public class BusinessTagLink : BaseEntity
    {
        public int BusinessTagLinkId { get; set; }
        public int BusinessId { get; set; }
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public virtual Business Business { get; set; }
        public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; } 
    }
```

I am trying to build a filter that will allow a user to filter down the list of businesses by interacting with a list of tags. I'm currently thinking they'll click on the tag and the ID of that tag will then get added to an int array, which will be passed to a filter method along with the full list of potential businesses. Something like:

`public static IQueryable<Business> Filter(this IQueryable<Business> businesses, int[] tagIds) { }`

What I'm really struggling with is how to use these parameters to return a list of filtered businesses. I think the LINQ query will make use of .Contains() and/or .Any() but I'm clueless beyond that.

`return businesses.Where(tagIds.Contains(x => x.BusinessTagLinks.Select(y => y.TagId)))`

`return businesses.Where(x => x.BusinessTagLinks.Any(y => y.TagId == [no idea how to target array here]));`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I meant to say, those last two lines of code are things I tried that obviously do not work.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: `return businesses.Where(x => x.BusinessTagLinks.Any(y => tagIds.Contains(y.TagId)));`

Comment: Apologies, I'm still learning how to ask good questions on here. It's EF Core 6.0.1 and SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return businesses.Where(x => x.BusinessTagLinks.Any(y => tagIdArray.Contains(y.TagId)));
```

This is basically saying give me the businesses where any of the business tag links has a tagId that exists in the array you're providing.

Comment: if convert `tagIdArray` to `HashSet`, then `Contains` might run faster?

Comment: If EF converts this to a SQL query, the TagId values will likely be passed as discrete parameters and referenced in a form similar to `WHERE y.TagId IN (@p1, @p2, @p3, ...)`. A C# HashSet will not make a difference. SQL Server may still build a plan that converts the `WHERE IN (...)` into a hash join though.